# Ruby: Dynamically Linked Arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I'm having some confusion about populating a new array with an existing array. It seems like if I set one array equal to the other, they become dynamically linked for the rest of the code. Is this a compiler attribute or am I not using the correct functions to store the values of one array in another? I hope this isn't an extremely basic question.

```
main_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
temp_arr = main_arr
puts "Main: " + main_arr.to_s 
puts "Temp: " + temp_arr.to_s

main_arr.clear
puts "Main: " + main_arr.to_s 
puts "Temp: " + temp_arr.to_s
```

Output:

```
Main: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Temp: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Main: []
Temp: []
```

Comment: If `a` is your array, `a.dup` will create a "shallow" copy. Suppose, for example, `a = [[1,2], [3,4]]`. Then `b = a.dup #=> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]`. So far, so good. Now lets add an element to `b`: `b << 'dog' #=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], "dog"]`. `a` is unchanged: `a #=> [[1,2], [3,4]]`. Consider `b[1][0] #=> 3`. Now let's change that element of `b` and see what happens to `a`: `b[1][0] = 'cat'; b #=> [[1, 2], ["cat", 4], "dog"]; a #=> [[1, 2], ["cat", 4]]`. Not what you were expecting? That's because `dup` creates a "shallow" copy of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

It's true, in your second line you are making `temp_array` point to the array object pointed by `main_arr`. If you want to make a copy of that array you can do

```
b = a.dup
```

Comment: Ah perfect! It's odd that this isn't covered in the Ruby documentation for arrays...

Comment: That's because `#dup` is on `Object`: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-dup

Comment: You can find the owner of an instance method like this: `Array.instance_method(:dup).owner #=>  Kernel`, or `[].method(:dup).owner #=> Kernel`. (Actually, `Array.instance_method(:dup) #=> #<UnboundMethod: Array(Kernel)#dup>` is enough, as the owner is shown in parenthesis.) `Kernel`'s instance methods are documented in [Object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html) (see second paragraph), which can be a bit confusing.  (`Kernel`'s module methods are documented in [Kernel](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html).)

Comment: I read through the Object documentation and I know understand what's happening with _clone_ and _dup_. I appreciate not only the help, but the supporting documentation.

Answer (score 0):

when you do this: `temp_arr = main_arr` it means that temp_arr is pointing to main_arr address. use `temp_arr = main_arr.dup` to copy it instead.

```
main_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
temp_arr = main_arr **means** temp_arr -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

so, when you do this `main_arr.clear -> []` and also `temp_arr -> []`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
main_arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
temp_arr = main_arr.dup

main_arr.clear
puts main_arr # => []
puts temp_arr # => [1,2,3,4,5]
```